# simple Graph Data Analysis, detect peaks, Detect Rowing Stroke

Tags: java, android, algorithm, accelerometer, graph-algorithm

I have problem with determinate when **new stroke**  is done at Sport Academic Rowing.

- I need simple **algorithm** which to **detect moment**, which characteristic are one global valley, then big rising which end with peak( look at picture 1 - catch phase, immediately after vertical dotted line
- The algorithm needs to be “adaptive”, because when you are rowing hard, the highest point is much higher than when you are paddling and reverse.
- **Input**: float acceleration
  Data is from accelerometer, so because of that data come continuously.
  I can find timestamp too.
- **Target:** That is cyclic graph, so i want to find how much cycles(strokes) are made per minute, for that i need to detect each one. (period between each two vertical dotted lines - - -)

**Rowing boat acceleration vs time graph:**
[image: rowing boat acceleration vs time graph]

**Thank you**

Comment: Here is a thesis that looks at the problem: https://scullr.com/docs/using-gps-and-accelerometer-data-for-rowing-race-tracking.pdf I don't think the accepted answer is going to work reliably because it depends too much on absolute values which depend on the speed of the boat.

Comment: If you are still working on this, I would be interested as well. I don't think it's a simple problem if you need to do this on-device and can't do advanced analysis. For example, I believe auto-correlation could be used to find the frequency of the stroke cycle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the data, a simple algorithm could be to divide acceleration into three distinct regions:

- less than -9 m/s^2
- between -9 m/s^2 and 0 m/s^2
- greater than 0 m/s^2

Then you construct a state machine with two states to detect each stroke. The first state is triggered when the acceleration is less than -9 m/s^2, and the second state is triggered when the acceleration is greater than 0 m/s^2. When the acceleration is in between, it doesn't change the state.

With your data, at 89.5s, it enters state 1, then enters state 2 at 89.8s, then state 1 again at 91.1s, etc.

Comment: Is possible to have problem with that the algorithm needs to be “adaptive”, because when you are rowing hard, the highest point is much higher than when you are paddling and reverse.

Comment: You'll have to test with your data then.I'm assuming that greater than 0 m/s^2 is a good indicator that you're rowing (so it doesn't matter what the peak is), and that less than -9 m/s^2 is when you're sliding your seat back to the front to be in position to row again. The -9 m/s^2 would probably change depending on the resistance.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use real time,
you can use realTime Databse from frirebase API

Comment: i don't need to store accelerometer data, i just need to analysis acceleration graph, and find that moment named at picture "catch phase"